# Sending an authenticated html CONNECT request with a Java socket?

Tags: java, sockets, http, proxy, protocols

My goal is to form a Java socket connection to a server, but there is an HTTP proxy standing in the way.

After much testing, I've concluded that

```
System.setProperty(http.proxyHost,"10.126.16.14");
System.setProperty(http.proxyPort,"8080");
System.setProperty(http.proxyUser,"username");
System.setProperty(http.proxyPass,"password");
```

doesn't affect Socket connections through a proxy, and neither does

```
Socket socket=new Socket(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.126.16.14",8080)));
socket.connect("minds1.no-ip.org",12345);
```

due to a bug in the JVM.  *sigh*

And so, I am tasked with implementing an HTTP CONNECT-method request using Java sockets.
After modifying some code I got off the internet (sorry I couldn't find the source!), I now have this method:

```
private static Socket createSocket(String address,int port,String proxHost,int proxPort, String proxUser,String proxPass) throws Exception
{
    Socket socket=null;
        socket = new Socket(proxHost, proxPort); //First step is to connect the socket to the proxy server itself.

        String proxRequest="CONNECT "+address+":"+port; //Next step is to send a formatted CONNECT request, including authentication if applicable
        if(proxUser!=null&&proxPass!=null)
            proxRequest=proxRequest+" HTTP/1.0\nProxy-Authorization: Basic "+toBase64String(proxUser+":"+proxPass)+"=";
        proxRequest=proxRequest+"\n\n";
        socket.getOutputStream().write(proxRequest.getBytes());

        byte[] tmpBuffer = new byte[512]; //Next we read the proxy server's response to see if the request got through.
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        int len = in.read(tmpBuffer, 0, tmpBuffer.length);
        if (len == 0) throw new SocketException("Invalid response from proxy");
        String proxResponse = new String(tmpBuffer, 0, len, "UTF-8");
        if (proxResponse.indexOf("200") != -1) //Proxy server has responded that the connection is successful!
        {
            if (in.available() > 0) in.skip(in.available()); //Cleanup input stream
            return socket; //Return the sucessfully-connected socket object
        }
        else throw new SocketException(proxResponse);
    return socket;
}
```

And this is the toBase64String method:

```
public static char[] Base64CharSet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".toCharArray();
public static String toBase64String(String original)
{
    byte[] buf=original.getBytes();
    int size = buf.length;
    char[] ar = new char[((size + 2) / 3) * 4];
    int a = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < size)
    {
        byte b0 = buf[i++];
        byte b1 = (i < size) ? buf[i++] : 0;
        byte b2 = (i < size) ? buf[i++] : 0;
        int mask = 0x3F;
        ar[a++] = Base64CharSet[(b0 >> 2) & mask];
        ar[a++] = Base64CharSet[((b0 << 4) | ((b1 & 0xFF) >> 4)) & mask];
        ar[a++] = Base64CharSet[((b1 << 2) | ((b2 & 0xFF) >> 6)) & mask];
        ar[a++] = Base64CharSet[b2 & mask];
    }
    switch (size % 3)
    {
        case 1: ar[--a] = '=';
        case 2: ar[--a] = '=';
    }
    return new String(ar);
}
```

Code looks good, and it compiles just fine with no external libraries.
Invoking the createSocket method, however, returns this response from the proxy server:

```
java.net.SocketException: HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error ( The specified Secure Socket
s Layer (SSL) port is not allowed. Forefront TMG is not configured to allow SSL
requests from this port. Most Web browsers use port 443 for SSL requests.  )
Via: 1.1 E291TMG1
Connection: close
Proxy-Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 780
```

So my question is, what does this error mean, can the problem be fixed by changing the code, and if so, how?

Comment: It seems perfectly clear. You can't use that port. NB the line terminator in HTTP is defined as `\r\n`, not `\n.`

Comment: Thanks, but 8080 is the only port the proxy server is set to run on- I don't understand why I can't use it, and why the response is talking about SSL when there's clearly no attempt at establishing a secure or encrypted connection in the code.

Comment: Is 'Forefront TMG' the proxy? Anyway 'it isn't configured to allow SSL requests from this port'.

Comment: Yes, Forefront TMG is the proxy software. But I'm not trying to make an SSL request, just a normal request. Any way I can do that?